# Local Database with Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight

What would be a good local database for a Silverlight application?  The database's main purpose is for local data caching and synchronization services. I do not believe that SQL anywhere or SQLite will work since they use unmanaged code which will not run under the silverlight sandbox

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use a new feature in SL 2 called "Isolated Storage"? It is fully support in local database (like Google Gear) but of course It is not a database. You can use XML file format to keep it.

- pros; User just need to install SL runtime.
- cons; It's not exactly a database

#### Find two references:

Moth said in his blog about it http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2008/04/isolatedstorage-in-siverlight-2-beta-1.html 
Dino made very good summary at http://www.ddj.com/windows/208300036?pgno=2

Answer (score 1):

@Aaron Fischer,

I'm very interested in this question too. I'm looking DB for XBAP (WPF in browser) apps. Here is my question ["What embedded database with Isolated Storage support can you recommend?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108399/what-embedded-database-with-isolated-storage-support-can-you-recommend)

SQLite & MSSQL CE (aka SQL anywhere) wouldn't work.

VistaDB is implemented in .NET and can work under constraints (it has support for Isolated Storage) but I'm looking for alternatives.

Another option is Sybase iAnywhere - but I'm not sure how to deploy it on end-user machine.

I'm going to try DB4objects for Silverlight. If it would work, I'll update the post.

Comment: There is also TurboDB which is "100%" managed http://www.dataweb.de/en/products/dotnet_database.html.  Not sure if this would be worth evaluating as well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is siaqodb. **Siaqodb** is real Silverlight client side object database, you can store an object with just one line of code and retrieve back objects via LINQ.For more info take a look at http://siaqodb.com

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [example](http://www.nerddawg.members.winisp.net/SilverGears/) it looks possible to use Google Gears and thus Sqlite. The major down side is the amount of integration work and the need to install yet one more platform on the client's computer.

Comment: I was thinking about Google Gears, but decided that it would be *too* much overhead

Answer (score 0):

If your caching needs are basic enough and you don't have so much data that you're doing it to minimize RAM usage, perhaps you don't even need a full-blown database.  You could create an object database of sorts using a structure such as a dictionary and put into it the objects that would otherwise be your table rows.  You could then serialize this data to a file in your local storage and deserialize it next time the app runs.  If your data structures are done well, you could even use Linq to query your object database.

If your primary goal is to minimize the number of times you have to pull the same data from your server, this could be something to consider.

On the other hand, this isn't the way to go if you have too much data or if you make frequent writes to the database (as it would then have to serialize the whole structure to disk every time).

If you do have too much data but still want to try this, you could see if there is a logical way to partition your data into multiple files that aren't likely to be needed at the same time.  Then you could push your unused data out to disk and load it back in next time the program needed it.  Of course, if you take this approach too far, you'll end up essentially writing your own database system anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to see two things.  1.)  Some kind of persisted local database support or 2.)  Some kind of actual database server support without the hassle of web services.

Personally, I'd take Access and OleDb.  :)

Answer (score 0):

One last thing... that the database type of functionality is something Flash/Flex doesn't offer... this would be a great way for Microsoft to differitiate Silverlight and really give it a leg up.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a sqlite port to c# called [csharp-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/)
This has promise once they find an acceptable name.

Comment: Except it is not the ADO.NET implementation, and is not actually usable.  It is a rough port of the C-Lib to C#.  So if you want to write to that interface in .Net and do all the mapping yourself it might work, but the last time I looked at the port it doesn't work and probably can't without major rework to support isolated storage concepts.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I think a LINQ provider is the optimal solution. As the storage space is limited, you don't really *need* tables and indexes, it would be convenient to have a simple way to store and query objects on the client via LINQ without having to deal with low-level file streams.

Comment: How do you write a Linq provider. It's really not easy.