# Accessing data from Silverlight Out of Browser

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight-5.0, out-of-browser

When Silverlight runs in Out of Browser mode and off line, can it get the Sql Server Data from a DataBase located in the local disk by means of an ADO Entity Data Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Entity Framework can run in Silverlight due to restrictions imposed by the Silverlight security model (and AFAIK System.Data.dll not available in Silverlight). Typically people use  WCF data services client in Silverlight to connect to a data service that exposes your database.

Comment: Ok, suppose I have a Silverlight app running in out of the browser mode, and it's offline, can I access a Sql Server database in the local hard disk, from this SL App?
Can I just develop a OOB Silverlight project and execute it as I would do if it was a WPF project?

Comment: I think it's hard. You can take a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111196/local-database-with-silverlight and http://silverlight4sqllib.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you. I get that you can only access some special files, but not a database...

Comment: @Rafael you can get full access to the hard drive (with caveats like the missing DriveInfo struct) or P/Invoke your way to whatever IF you use a signed app with elevated trust since SL5.

Comment: Another problem with accessing database is that System.Data.dll is a mixed assembly (i.e. it contains both native and managed code) and Silverlight AFAIK Silverlight runtime cannot execute native code...