# SQL Server Compact Edition (connect from external connection)

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

I'm working with a device (barcode printer) that can connect to a database to retrieve some of it's information. I want to host SQL Server Compact Edition on the PC that is talking to the printer. Will the SQL Server Compact allow an external connection from the printer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will for sure. It have limitations, but it can be connected from another machine.

[What are the limitations to SQL Server Compact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407521/what-are-the-limitations-to-sql-server-compact-or-how-does-one-choose-a-datab)

Comment: thanks for that and the links on limitations. I'll try it out soon.

Comment: from this link you're right. T http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172436.aspx