# SQL Server Compact Edition - sequence column?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have a simple desktop application that is using SQL Server Compact (3.5 and about to be upgraded to 4.0).

In my main customers table, in addition to the `ID` column - which is the PK and is auto incremented, I need to hold a `Number` column that starts in some number (20000) and is unique.

The option of computing the next number by the existing highest row is not a good one - if other client is adding a customer between my first selection to my inserting - I'll have a problem.

As pointed in [many](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174639.aspx) [places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407521/what-are-the-limitations-to-sql-server-compact-or-how-does-one-choose-a-datab), SqlCE auto incremented column should be `Identity` column, and in each table could be only one `Identity` column.

Is there other practice you know to solve this problem?

BTW - I am using Linq to ADO .net.

**Edit:**

Just found this link and discovered that I can use even the Identity option with linq to Entities framework:
http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/04/solutions-to-server-generated-keys-and.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this action is wrong basically
but if you persist that
you need a transaction when you select max value of your column.so you ensure another user can't update(and change max value) until this action complete.

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{         
    // Set new NumericColumn 
    entity.NumericColumn = (db.Context.Rotations.Max(r => (long?)r.NumericColumn ) ?? 20000) + 1;
    // Insert entity
    db.Context.Rotations.AddObject(entity);
    db.Context.SaveChanges();

    transaction.Complete();
}
```