# Is it not recommended to use SQL Server CE in catalog based websites

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I have build a catalog system which use SQL CE as database. After deploying it at hosting provider (GoDaddy.com), the performance was pathetic. Whenever data access is performed it takes a pretty long time to retrieve the products. Many a times, i keep getting this error:

```
There is a file sharing violation. A different process might be using the file. D:\Hosting\8750445\html\App_Data\PriceCompare-Prod.sdf**
```

If this problem is coming up when i am the only one surfing the website, what will happen if numerous people are accessing the website at the same time?

Should one avoid using SQL CE for production databases in such catalog based sites or there is something wrong with my hosting provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL CE is a great tool if you want to use it on a windows phone 7 or if you have a one user (throw away) app. For a website you should really use a database which was build for multi user access. For more informations see the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407521/what-are-the-limitations-to-sql-server-compact-or-how-does-one-choose-a-data).