# ASP.NET Web Pages - Storing nvarchar more than 4000 character

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I'm using Microsoft WebMatrix to develop a small website in ASP.NET Web Pages. I have a database table with a column that may contain more than 4000 characters.

Nvarchar has a limit of 4000 characters. When using SQL Server I can just use Nvarchar(Max). Is there anyway I can do this using WebMatrix's database designer? Is it a limitation in the database and will I need to migrate it to SQL Server?

Just a side-question - does WebMatrix use a SQL Server Compact 4.0 database?

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407521/what-are-the-limitations-to-sql-server-compact-or-how-does-one-choose-a-data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server Compact is the default database for web matrix, http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/migrating-sql-server-compact-to-sql-server-express-with-webmatrix.

nvarchar(max) is not supported in SQL Server Compact, but you could use nText. However, I don't believe you can use an nText column in WHERE or GROUP BY clauses.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think I will migrate to SQL Server once my site is ready to be published.